# 'exported: true' has no effect in '_specialize' attribute in Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode12

On my machine, Xcode has automatically upgraded itself to latest version Xcode 12.5. And I'm facing issue now in building my project. It was running perfectly yesterday with Xcode 12.4, no code change nor library change. Literally the same codebase.

Anyone face this issue with solution fixed?

Error message received:

`'exported: true' has no effect in '_specialize' attribute`
[image]

**Tried (but non is helping):**

1. Restart machine
2. Kill and restart Xcode
3. Clean build
4. Remove derived data

Comment: Looks like a problem with the CryptoSwift pod. Try deintegrating and starting over with your pods.

Comment: I have temporarily downloaded 12.4 version to continue my work, will re-visit this topic again. Thanks for your recommendation. I believe `pod update` might resolve this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with running `pod update` instead of pointing to a specific version in my `Podfile`

Otherwise, you could also follow what @coryhowell pointed out,

> removed the pod and added it as a Swift Package (Version 1.4.0)

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '11.4'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'myAppp' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.1'
  pod 'CryptoSwift'
end
```

**Podfile.lock** - auto-created, then pointed to latest version of the CryptoSwift

```
PODS:
  - Alamofire (4.8.2)
  - Countly (20.11.1):
    - Countly/Core (= 20.11.1)
  - Countly/Core (20.11.1)
  - Crashlytics (3.12.0):
    - Fabric (~> 1.9.0)
  - CryptoSwift (1.4.0)
  - Device (3.1.2)
  - Fabric (1.9.0)

..
...
not showing all lines
....
......
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm having the same issue with the CryptoSwift pod. Xcode 12.5 is using Swift 5.4. I don't think CryptoSwift has been updated for swift 5.4 yet. I switched back to Xcode 12.4 and ran pod install. It's building again on Xcode 12.4. The Latest version of CryptoSwift only supports Swift 5.3

**Update**

I was unable to get CryptoSwift to update past version 1.2.0 using cocoa pods. I removed the pod and added it as a Swift Package (Version 1.4.0). I was able to build using Xcode 12.5

[Confirmed this was fixed in CryptoSwift 1.3.2](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/864#issuecomment-829444430)

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the old version
2. reinstall the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This is because `@_specialize` label is changed in Swift 5.4(Xcode 12.5), you can just make a substitution by regular expression:

```
@_specialize\(([^,]+),\s([^)]+)\)
@_specialize\($2\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment `all @_specialize(exported: true, where T == ArraySlice<UInt8>)` etc... and it should work.